# How do I solve a skel is not defined at skel-layers-min.js django framework error

Tags: javascript, django, skel

Hello there my fellow devs. I am a backend beginner Django developer and I used a premade template from Htmlup.com. I have changed all the links to `{'static "{file location}"'}`. When I run it on `localhost` it gives me this error:

```
init.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: {(intermediate value)} is not a functionat init.js:15
```

I have tried adding:

```
var helios_settings = {
    //other settings here
    skel: {prefix: "{% static '/css' %}" },
    // other settings here
}
```

to the `init.js` file but it's still not working. Please help me with the issue.